# Find out why a Kubernetes cluster was restarted on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

This has happened twice in the last two months - during a weekend the entire GKE cluster is restarted.

It happens even though the cluster is set to manual upgrade (release channel is set to "None").

Is there a way to find out why the GKE cluster was restarted?

Answer (score 4):

As stated in [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/release-channels#no_channel):

> **No channel**
>
> Regardless of whether your cluster is enrolled in a release channel or not, cluster control planes are always [upgraded on a regular basis](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/upgrades#automatic_cp_upgrades).
>
> . . .
>
> Automatic upgrades are typically performed in stages over multiple weeks. Infrastructure security is high priority for GKE, and as such control planes are upgraded on a regular basis, and cannot be disabled. However, you can apply [maintenance windows and exclusions](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/maintenance-windows-and-exclusions) to temporarily suspend upgrades for control planes and nodes.

Use `gcloud container operations list --filter="TYPE:UPGRADE_MASTER"` to see recent control plane upgrades:

```
$ gcloud container operations list --filter="TYPE:UPGRADE_MASTER"
NAME                              TYPE            LOCATION    TARGET  STATUS_MESSAGE  STATUS  START_TIME                      END_TIME
operation-1631397153397-fc924191  UPGRADE_MASTER  us-west1-b  prod                    DONE    2021-09-11T22:05:53.397098204Z  2021-09-11T22:10:04.559303783Z
```